# Is there a way (API/Scripting) to work with Virtual PC?

Tags: api, virtual-pc

Is there a way to interact with Virtual PC<sup>1</sup>?

Looking to do basic things like startup and shutdown (with choice of save or turn off etc..) specific VM's.

Any solution other than simulating key presses would be fine, for example

- WMI
- COM+
- ADSI
- PowerShell

1 - Specifically for Virtual PC as in Microsoft Virtual PC (i.e. the one that runs on Vista and earlier), not Windows Virtual PC (i.e. the Win7 one)

Comment: Why were you so quick to accept the "no" answer? I've been told that it is possible with PowerShell, but haven't found any details on how to do it. I would have left the question open until finding the "yes" answer.

Comment: All my own investigation proved the same answer. For Virtual PC Powershell is of not help either :(

Comment: For more answers see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/971590/328397

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, no, see http://www.aspdeveloper.net/Virtual_PC/rn-739-16434_Virtual_PC_API.aspx .

Comment: That's an old post and says that there will be one for Virtual PC 2005. Doesn't that mean that Virtual PC 2007 would have one also?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite what you're after but there are a whole set of command line parameters you can use on Virtual PC.exe to start and pause VMs as well as set screen modes and disable/enable various options.

You can find them on this [MS KB 831501 article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831501).

> "Virtual PC.exe" [-singlepc] [-quiet]
>   [-usehostdiskcache] [-pc
>   virtual_machine_name  [-disableclose]
>   [-disableopt] [-s3bitclip] [-setbiosno
>   bios_serial_number] [-setassettag
>   asset_tag] [-extnetworking] [-launch]
>   [{-fullscreen|-window}] [-geometry
>   widthxheight{+|-}x offset{+|-}y
>   offset] [{-minimize|-restore}]
>   [{-pause|-resume}]] [-help]
>   [-registervm filename.vmc] [-startvm
>   filename.vmc]